# How to select the first and last elements in an irregularly shaped numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've been having a hard time finding an answer for this online, so I thought I'd query good ol' Stack Overflow.

I have this example:

```
v = np.array([
    np.array([1, 1]),
    np.array([1, 2]),
    np.array([1, 3]),
    np.array([1, 4]),
    np.array([1, 5]),
    np.array([2, 1]),
    np.array([2, 2]),
    np.array([2, 3]),
    np.array([3, 1]),
    np.array([3, 2]),
    np.array([3, 3]),
    np.array([3, 4]),
    np.array([4, 1]),
    np.array([4, 2]),
    np.array([4, 3]),
    np.array([4, 4]),
    np.array([4, 5]),
    np.array([4, 6]),
])

k = np.split(v[:, 1], np.unique(v[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])

# output below

[
    np.array([1,2,3,4,5]),
    np.array([1,2,3]),
    np.array([1,2,3,4]),
    np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
]
```

My aim is to select the first and last element of each array in the output list. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
k = np.array(k, dtype=object)
new_k = (([:, 0], [:, -1]))
```

But alas, this is not possible. Maybe there is a way to rewrite the line that creates `k` to just have the first and last item?

Notice that I am trying to accomplish this with no list comprehension, defining functions, or loops - just "vanilla" numpy. If that's not feasible, any direction toward the next most efficient way of accomplishing this would be great.

Comment: You have a list of arrays.  Wrapping it in an object dtype array does not change that essential nature.

Comment: `[a[[0, -1]] for a in out]`, you can't do it in numpy alone in a vectorial way

Comment: @hpaulj This question (both the comment and post) is going to show my ignorance, but I don't get it. `np.array()` takes in a list and converts it to a ctype array. Why would I expect anything different?

Comment: Because numpy arrays make sense when they don't have an object dtype. They are otherwise no better than python lists.

Comment: @mozway Okay, sure. But there is nothing "better" than list comprehension to solve this problem? I can't rewrite the initial line that creates the list?

Comment: `np.split` used a list comprehension to creat the list of slices.  You stuck with treating each of those arrays individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.unique` operation selects the first occurrence of a value. Doing that with the normal array means it selects the first of each group, and doing the same for the reversed array means it selects the last of each group.

```py
import numpy as np

v = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [1, 4],
    [1, 5],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 1],
    [3, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [4, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 6],
])

first_values = v[np.unique(v[:, 0], return_index=True)[1], 1]
last_values = v[::-1][np.unique(v[::-1, 0], return_index=True)[1], 1]

k = np.vstack((first_values, last_values)).T
```

This gives the desired result,

```py
array([[1, 5],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 6]])
```

Comment: Would you have to `.T` if you used hstack?

Comment: `hstack` wouldn't work because `first_values` and `last_values` are shape `(4,)` not `(4,1)`. Using `hstack` here would just create an array of size `(8,)` rather than the desired `(4,2)`. To use `hstack`, you'd need to either (1) reshape the arrays first or (2) `np.hstack((first_values[:,None], last_values[:,None]))`. To me, using `vstack` with a transpose is clearer.

Comment: A variante on the `vstack`: `np.stack((first_values, last_values), axis=1)`